# working with CSV

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfml

I'm running the following query and  QoQ . Could you tell me how should I proceed for the "Download  CSV" file option?

```
<!--- QoQ for FIRSTCONN --->

<cfquery datasource = "XX.XX.X.XX" name="master1">
     SELECT STR_TO_DATE(date_format(Timedetail,'%m-%d-%Y'),'%m-%d-%Y') as FIRSTCONN
            , COUNT(Timedetail) as FIRSTOccurances
            , EVENTS 
     FROM  MyDatabase
     WHERE EVENTS = "FIRST" 
     GROUP BY FIRSTCONN ;
</cfquery> 

<!--- Detail Query --->

<cfquery dbtype="query" name="detail1">
    SELECT  *
    FROM master1 
    WHERE FIRSTCONN  >= <cfqueryparam value="#form.startdate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"> 
    AND   FIRSTCONN  <  <cfqueryparam value="#dateAdd('d', 1,form.enddate)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">;
</cfquery>  


<!--- QoQ for SECONDCONN --->

<cfquery datasource = "XX.XX.X.XX" name="master2">
    SELECT STR_TO_DATE(date_format(Timedetail,'%m-%d-%Y'),'%m-%d-%Y') as SECONDCONN
           , COUNT(Timedetail) as SECONDOccurances
           , EVENTS 
    FROM  MyDatabase
    WHERE EVENTS = "SECOND" 
    GROUP BY SECONDCONN ;
</cfquery> 


<cfquery dbtype="query" name="detail2">
    SELECT  *
    FROM   master2 
    WHERE  SECONDCONN  >= <cfqueryparam value="#form.startdate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"> 
    AND    SECONDCONN  <  <cfqueryparam value="#dateAdd('d', 1,form.enddate)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">;
</cfquery>  


<cfchart format="flash"  chartwidth="1000" chartheight="500" scalefrom="0" scaleto="50000" xAxisTitle="Dates" yaxistitle="Number of Connections">
     <cfchartseries  query="detail1" type="line" itemColumn="FIRSTCONN" valueColumn="FIRSTOccurances" > 
     <cfchartseries  query="detail2" type="line" itemColumn="SECONDCONN" valueColumn="SECONDOccurances" > 
     </cfchartseries>
</cfchart>[/CODE]

The cfform code and cfscript code I'm using is as follows:

[CODE]<cfform format="flash" preloader ="false">


<cfformgroup type="horizontal">

  <cfinput type="dateField" name="startdate" label="Start Date" width="100" value="#form.startdate#">
  <cfinput type="dateField" name="enddate" label="End Date" width="100" value="#form.enddate#">
  <cfinput name="submitApply" type="submit" value = "Apply">
  <cfinput name="cancel" type="submit" value="Download CSV">

</cfformgroup>


<cfscript>
    var tl ='';
    var nl = (Chr( 13 ) & Chr( 10 ));
    var fileContent = createObject("java","java.lang.StringBuffer").init();
    var counter =1;
    fileContent.append( 'FIRST');
     fileContent.append(nl);
            for(i=1;i<=detail1.recordCount;i=i+1){
                tl = detail1.FIRST;
                fileContent.append(tl);
                fileContent.append(nl);
            }




  fileContent.append( 'SECOND');
     fileContent.append(nl);
            for(i=1;i<=detail2.recordCount;i=i+1){
                tl = detail2.SECOND;
                fileContent.append(tl);
                fileContent.append(nl);
            }           

</cfscript>

<cfset absoluteFilePathAndName = " C:\ColdFusion8\runtime\servers\coldfusion\SERVER-INF\temp\wwwroot-tmp\">

<cfset realtiveFilePathAndName = " C:\ColdFusion8\runtime\servers\coldfusion\SERVER-INF\temp\wwwroot-tmp\">

<cffile action="write" file="#absoluteFilePathAndName#" output="#fileContent.toString()#"/>
<a href="#realtiveFilePathAndName#>Download</a>
```

Desired Output:

I have attached the [image] for the output below. Please find it attached.

Basically, if a date range is 21June to 21 July. The output must be as shown in the image. (I have omitted THIRDCONN etc for the sake of simplicity in my code).

I tried to attempt to the above problem,Do I need to write fileContent.append() for each and every column? Please let me know if I'm wrong.

P.S. I'm new to CF and haven't done this before.

Thanks

Comment: So you want to generate CSV data from a recordset? Is all the above bumpf basically a very long-winded way of asking that?

Comment: Yes, I want to generate CSV when a user click on Download button.

Comment: No no no. "creating CSV data from a recordset" is a Stack Overflow question; "how do I finish writing my code for this specific piece of work" is soliciting free consultancy. You need to do your own work. And to do your own work, you need to break the task at hand down into general chunks. First chunk: you need to know how to create CSV data from a recordset. Not even "this specific record set", but the general solution for "recordset to CSV". I suggest you start by googling "cfml query to csv".

Comment: I wrote a cfscript if you look at my code properly and asking questions on that. Would you like me to do more research?

Comment: Yuo shoudl start by getting rid of all the crap that's got nothing to do with a) the recordset that has the data you want to convert to CSV; b) the code that creates CSV data. Your question doesn't need forms and charts and HTML and all that stuff. Just start with a record set. And work out how to make CSV data out of it (I see no code above that does that... you might need to look up what CSV data looks like, too). Like I said, break the overall requirement into chunks, and resolve each chuck. Whilst learning how to do each chunk, don't worry about the over-all big picture.

Comment: @AdamCameron - Agreed on most of that. However, he did include his attempt at generating a csv (albeit after the extraneous chart/form code). Tan - You did not articulate the question clearly, which is "how to export **multiple** queries to a *single* CSV file". Nor did you explain the problem with your current code. While we can make some educated guesses, we should not have to run the code just to understand the problem. (cont'd)

Comment: That said, I think you are making it more complex than it needs to be. Start [by generating a *single* resultset](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17796580/104223), not multiples, then take it step by step as suggested.

Comment: @Leigh there's some code that generates a string. It's not CSV format though. Hence my observation "you might need to look up what CSV data looks like, too".

Comment: @AdamCameron - True enough. That is why I said "attempt" ;) But agreed about tackling this in smaller chunks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using *separate* queries makes this a LOT more difficult than necessary. For it to work, you essentially need to [pivot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table) or transpose the rows of *each* query into separate columns. Not an easy task, unless all of your queries are guaranteed to contain the exact same dates, in the same order (unlikely).

If you have a fixed number of events, it is *much* simpler to use a single database query to generate all of counts. Use a [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) statements to build the counts based on the "Events" value:

(Note: This ***cannot*** be done inside a QoQ. They do not support `CASE`).

```
 SELECT STR_TO_DATE(date_format(Timedetail,'%m-%d-%Y'),'%m-%d-%Y') as TheDate
        , SUM( CASE WHEN EVENTS = 'First' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS FirstConn
        , SUM( CASE WHEN EVENTS = 'Second' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS SecondConn
        , SUM( CASE WHEN EVENTS = 'Third' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS ThirdConn
 FROM  YourTableName
 WHERE Timedetail  >= <cfqueryparam value="#form.startdate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date"> 
 AND   Timedetail  <  <cfqueryparam value="#dateAdd('d', 1,form.enddate)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">
 GROUP BY STR_TO_DATE(date_format(Timedetail,'%m-%d-%Y'),'%m-%d-%Y')
```

Once you have all the results in a single query, you can do the rest on your own. As Adam mentioned, just do a search on ColdFusion query to csv. There are *tons* of examples you can follow, as well as a number of pre-built functions for converting queries to CSV:

- [`CSVFormat()`](http://www.cflib.org/udf/CSVFormat)
- [`QueryToCSV()`](http://www.cflib.org/index.cfm?event=page.udfbyid&udfid=556)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Just one question, does Query to CSV means that the data would be outputted in an Excel sheet? Or do I need to look at cfspreadsheet option? Just wanted to makes sure I'm heading in right direction.

Comment: No, CSV means ... [CSV format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Example). The program assigned to open .csv files is up to the user. Typically Excel, but it could also be a different program.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Please take a look at my updated code.

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment and code. I have figured out other way to work around with this problem and now getting the CSV generated code in my output. Thanks

Comment: @Tan - Yikes! Try not to erase questions and replace them with a completely new one .. because now the answer above makes absolutely no sense! :) Instead make small updates/edits. If there is a *drastic* change, it is best to open a separate question. But do not forget to close out the old one. FYI: I have rolled back the original question to preserve the context of this thread.

Comment: Okay. Since the original question was answered, please close out this thread. If the final code involves more than the query above, feel free to post it as a separate answer (just the parts relating to generating your CSV file)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34017/discussion-between-tan-and-leigh)